# In how many ways 6 coins can be chosen out of 20 coins of type A, 10 of type of B and 7 of type C?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I know a similar question exists, but I am not satisfied with the explanation

The formula used is $\binom {n+r-1}{r-1}$, where $n=6$ and $r=3$

I don’t understand how the is the correct formula. It is the number of solutions of
$x_1+x_2+x_3..x_r=n$ where every solution is non negative.

It can also be described as ‘number of ways of distributing n identical objects among r groups’

Here, the objects aren’t identical, and neither are they being distributed into groups. Then how does using this make sense?

Comment: If you see any type, number of available coins are more than $6$. So it comes down to choosing $x_1$ of type $A$, $x_2$ of type $B$ and $x_3$ of type $C$ such that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 6$.

Comment: If coins in each type are also different, then the type has no impact, in which case should it just be  choosing 6 from 37 different coins?

Comment: @BrightStar, that sounds right. But in this question it appears to be assumed that coins of the same type are indistinguishable.

Comment: Think of the objects being distributed as six identical "coin slots", not coins. The "distributing them into groups" is choosing how many slots will contain each type of coin.

Comment: @karl in that case, 8*7/2 = 28 as formula in the question shows.

Comment: If $a$ is the number of coins of type A, $b$ the number of type B, and $c$ the number of type C, then we are asked for the number of solutions to $a+b+c=6$ in nonnegative integers.

Comment: The intuition behind the formula is [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Comment: @karl Exactly right:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem seems to stem from your observations below:

**It can also be described as ‘number of ways of distributing n identical objects among r groups’**

**Here, the objects aren’t identical, and neither are they being distributed into groups. Then how does using this make sense?**

Well, to understand why this formula applies, one way is to imagine that the coins are identical, and are distributed to three bins, $A,B,C$, where they magically transform into coins of type $A, B,$ and  $C$ respectively.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, but it isn’t exactly intuitive. Almost as if the situation is changed to force it work with the stars and bars formula

Comment: We are able to pool the numbers because there are enough of each type. There is a classic ice cream parlor problem you could search for which is analogous.

Comment: http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3/sec_stars-and-bars.html

Comment: Also don’t we have a separate formula for number of combinations where we have p,q,r identical objects $(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)-1$?